# Make image's z-index change on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried a lot of things, but nothing is working.

When I click on an mage, I want it's z-index to be "9999". When I click to show another image, I want the previous image's z-index to go back to "0".

So basically, I only want one image to show at a time - I want a specific function to run for each image.

http://jsfiddle.net/WarrenBee/a78R7/

PLEASE help me!

Comment: Always put the relevant code **in the question itself**, don't just link. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your JavaScript to this:

```
$('.char').click(function () {
    $('.char img').css({'z-index' : '0'});
    $(this).children('img').css({'z-index' : '9999'});
});
```

This will set the z-index of all imgs inside a char class back to 0, before setting the one that was clicked to 9999.

Comment: I voted your answer because it was really simple and didn't waste space. I do have one more question if you don't mind...

Comment: When the z-index of the clicked image turns to 9999, how can I set a variable to be equal to that image's ID/class? I want to send that variable to a switch statement so that a Biography div can display when a person's image is clicked

Comment: This is one solution http://jsfiddle.net/cxHY7/ - I gave each of the char classes an ID of biog<num>. In the javascript I get this ID and strip off 'biog' to just get the number. This is then passed to the displayBiog function. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just remember the last image and value and put the old value back:

```
var lastImage, lastZIndex;
$('.char').click(function () { 
    var thisImage = $(this).children('img');
    if (lastImage) {
        lastImage.css('z-index', lastZIndex);
    }
    lastImage = thisImage;
    lastZIndex = thisImage.css('z-index');
    thisImage.css({'z-index' : '9999'})
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a78R7/1/)

Ideally, avoid creating global variables by wrapping all of that in a function:

```
(function() {
    var lastImage, lastZIndex;
    $('.char').click(function () { 
        var thisImage = $(this).children('img');
        if (lastImage) {
            lastImage.css('z-index', lastZIndex);
        }
        lastImage = thisImage;
        lastZIndex = thisImage.css('z-index');
        thisImage.css({'z-index' : '9999'})
    });
})();
```

[Further updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a78R7/3/)